# CSS Flexbox: Alignment problems

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

I have several flex-items within one flex-container:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-66">Box 1 | 66%</div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-33">Box 2 | 33%</div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-33">Box 3 | 33%</div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-33">Box 4 | 33%</div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-100">Box 5 | 100%</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately Box 1 contains a lot of text. Boxes 2, 3 and 4 only have little text. Although Box 2, 3 and 4 would fit the height of Box 1, only Box 1 appears on the right of Box 1. The other Boxes are displayed below box (see picture for details).

Is there a way to make the boxes fill the vertical whitespace before they start in a new line?

My aim is, that box 3 and 4 appear directly below box 2. Only when they reach the same height as box 1, a new line should be opened.

The result should look like my second image:
[image]
[image]

```css
/*********** General *******/
.flex-container {
    background: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -10px;
}

/** st_justifyContent START **/
.flex-justify-start {
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-justify-end {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-justify-center {
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-justify-space-evenly {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
/** st_justifyContent END **/


/** st_flexDirection START **/
.flex-row {
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}
/** st_flexDirection END **/


/*************** Single Item ***************/
/** st_width START **/
.flex-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-item > .flex-container {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.flex-item > .flex-container > .flex-item {
    padding: 0;
}

.flex-item-width-25 {
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
}

.flex-item-width-33 {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 20px);
    float: right;
}

.flex-item-width-50 {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.flex-item-width-66 {
    width: calc(66.66666% - 20px);
}

.flex-item-width-75 {
    width: calc(75% - 20px);
}

.flex-item-width-100 {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

/** st_alignSelf START **/
.flex-align-self-start {
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.flex-align-self-center {
    align-self: center;
}

.flex-align-self-end {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.flex-align-self-stretch {
    align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container flex-justify-end flex-row">
 <div class="flex-item flex-item-width-66 flex-align-self-start" style="order: 1; flex-grow: 1">
  <h3 class="flex-item-title">Box 1 | 66%</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
 <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
 <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. </p>
 <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item flex-item-width-33 flex-align-self-start" style="order: 1; flex-grow: 1">
  <h3 class="flex-item-title">Box 2 | 33%</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item flex-item-width-33 flex-align-self-start" style="order: 1; flex-grow: 1">
  <h3 class="flex-item-title">Box 3 | 33%</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item flex-item-width-33 flex-align-self-start" style="order: 1; flex-grow: 1">
  <h3 class="flex-item-title">Box 4 | 33%</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item flex-item-width-100 flex-align-self-start" style="order: 1; flex-grow: 1">
  <h3 class="flex-item-title">Box 5 | 100%</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what actually you want. you mean Box 1 display on right side and Box 2 goes down? elaborate your question

Comment: I want box 3 and 4 to appear directly below box 2. Only when these boxes reach the same height as box 1, a new line should be opened.

Comment: can you post the snippet of your code.

Comment: @MerajKhan code was added.

Comment: check I added the snippet of your code if it is useful appreciate :)

Comment: This is not possible with flexbox. You might try CSS Grid which might give you more control.

Comment: On the other hand this is **precisely** how floats work.

Answer (score 0):

See below code I think you want like this.

```css
/*********** General *******/
.flex-container {
    background: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -10px;
}

/** st_justifyContent START **/
.flex-justify-start {
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-justify-end {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-justify-center {
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-justify-space-evenly {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
/** st_justifyContent END **/


/** st_flexDirection START **/
.flex-row {
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}
/** st_flexDirection END **/


/*************** Single Item ***************/
/** st_width START **/
.flex-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-item > .flex-container {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.flex-item > .flex-container > .flex-item {
    padding: 0;
}

.flex-item-width-25 {
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
}

.flex-item-width-33 {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 20px);
    float: right;
}

.flex-item-width-50 {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.flex-item-width-66 {
    width: calc(66.66666% - 20px);
}

.flex-item-width-75 {
    width: calc(75% - 20px);
}

.flex-item-width-100 {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

/** st_alignSelf START **/
/*.flex-align-self-start {
    align-self: flex-start;
}*/

.flex-align-self-center {
    align-self: center;
}

.flex-align-self-end {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.flex-align-self-stretch {
    align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container flex-justify-end flex-row">
 <div class="flex-item flex-item-width-66 flex-align-self-start" style="order: 1; flex-grow: 1">
  <h3 class="flex-item-title">Box 1 | 66%</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
 <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
 <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. </p>
 <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item flex-item-width-33 flex-align-self-start" style="order: 1; flex-grow: 1">
  <h3 class="flex-item-title">Box 2 | 33%</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item flex-item-width-33 flex-align-self-start" style="order: 1; flex-grow: 1">
  <h3 class="flex-item-title">Box 3 | 33%</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item flex-item-width-33 flex-align-self-start" style="order: 1; flex-grow: 1">
  <h3 class="flex-item-title">Box 4 | 33%</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-item flex-item-width-100 flex-align-self-start" style="order: 1; flex-grow: 1">
  <h3 class="flex-item-title">Box 5 | 100%</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a little. But I don't want the boxes on the right to stretch over the full height of box 1. In my example box 3 should take the place below box 2 as long as the height of box 2 + height of box 3 is less than the height of box 1. And so on...

Comment: Add image how you want.

Comment: Image added to original question :)